# Excel VBA Write filename based on system date

Tags: excel, vba, date-comparison

I am trying to write a VBA Script in Excel that will save a file and will give a pre-determined name. One of the criteria is that if it isn't past 11 AM, then it should add to the filename "H12". If it is past 11 AM, then it should add "H16".

Here's what I have so far, regarding this specific part (there is more code that is not relevant to show here:

```
Dim SaveTime As Integer
SaveTime = Round(Timer / 3600, 0)
dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd")
FolderName = "path/to/file"
If SaveTime < 11 Then
    With Destwb
       .SaveAs FolderName _
                    & "\" & Destwb.Sheets(1).Name & dt & "H12", _
                        FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
       .Close False
    End With
    Else
        With Destwb
            .SaveAs FolderName _
                    & "\" & Destwb.Sheets(1).Name & dt & "H16", _
                        FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
            .Close False
        End With
     End If
```

The script is working properly except this part because it is always saving the files as "H16". Ran this 45 minutes ago and it should've written it as "H12". I am sure I am not doing the time comparison correctly. I have tried comparing `if dt < "11:00"` but that does not work either.

Can someone give me a hand here?

Thanks in advance!

edit: added one last detail.

Comment: It looks like this code is correct. Why do you think you are not doing the right thing ?

Comment: Because it is always writing H16 instead of H12, as it should have done 45 minutes ago :)

Comment: Which value of savetime did you expect 45 min ago ? 11 ?

Comment: yes. 45 minutes ago, the system date was before 11 AM, so it should have added the text string "H12" to the filename which did not happen. Instead, it added the string "H16".

Comment: Looks like you used `Round` when you actually wanted to extract the hour part with `Hour` ;)

Comment: Should it then be `SaveTime = Hour(Timer /3600, 0)`?

Comment: Should be `savetime=hour(now)` as Martin mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not entirely sure what your error was (which line caused with Err#?), I do hope this helps you solve your problem

```
(...)
Dim SaveTime As Integer
SaveTime = Hour(Now)

FolderName = "C:\Users\b036081\NoBackupData"
FileFormatNum = 51 ' that's xlsx without macros

    With Destwb

        If SaveTime < 11 Then
            .SaveAs FolderName _
                & "\" & .Sheets(1).Name & dt & "H12", FileFormatNum
            '.Close False
        Else
            .SaveAs FolderName _
                    & "\" & .Sheets(1).Name & dt & "H16", FileFormatNum
            '.Close False
        End If

    End With
```

- I noticed you used `/` in your `FolderName`-placeholder, but I trust you know that you have to use `\` as a path separator in VBA
- I'm not sure if you actually want to do `SaveTime = Round(Timer / 3600, 3)`. If your goal is to extract the hour of the date, instead of for example return `5` at `04:35`, you could use something like `Hour(Now)`, which returns an Integer
- I wrapped the `With Destwb` around the `If`, instead of the other way around, which cleans up your code a bit

Edit: Updated code with working solution

Comment: I'm not sure how your code differs from mine. And I'm not getting an error. The entire script works perfectly fine. The problem is that it is not evaluating the system date properly. In simpler terms, I need it to check the system date and if it is not past 11 AM, then add the text string "H12" to the text file. If it is past 11AM, then add "H16". It is this simple but I am not doing the correct hour/date evaluation

Comment: What you do is: you add "H16" after `10:30:01` because you round your timer to full hours, instead of extracting the hour-part. I believe i wrote that in my post ;) Use `Hour(Now)` instead of `Round(Timer / 3600, 0)`

Comment: Ah, I understood you now. In a couple of minutes, I will test your suggestion and will give you a reply about it. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, that solves the problem!! Thank you very much!